# Background-image  javascript

Tags: javascript, css

добрый день как сделать бесконечный цикл изменениния свойства background-image плавный на javascript, знаю как сделать на чистом  CSS.спасибо

Comment: @ksardas, если вы будете задавать вопросы на русском языке, то вероятность того, что вам здесь ответят, сильно возрастёт.

Comment: есть свойство background-css, и 2 фона, мне нужно чтобы они чередовались, мне надо функция для бесконечной смены фонов(jquery,javscript)set interval...мне не надо слайдеры, я знаю как это делать на javacript через <img>,но мне надо через свойство CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вспомнив курсы телепатов, я готов предположить что вам нужна плавная смена картинок:

- [Плавный переход css спрайта у кнопки](http://www.yellowlemon.net/javascript/effect/animations-bottom-css-sprite)
- [Скрипт: Плавная смена картинки](http://k-dezign.ru/publ/java_skripty/skript_plavnaja_smena_kartinki/16-1-0-85)
- [Простой скрипт плавной смены картинок на JQuery](http://wmdn.ru/javascript/smooth-changing-rotate-images-script-on-jquery/)

Comment: спасибо, но по ясновидению  у Вас 4;) в хтмл не будет вообще тега <img> только 1 div и надо анимировать его свойство background-image(менять 2 картинки)

Comment: Боюсь что ограничиться стилями тут не получится. Проблема в том, что менять прозрачность background-image нельзя.
Возможно можно как то исхитриться с помощью псевдоэлементов, но больше 2х картинок Вы таким образом не сможете менять =)

В любом случае если получится реализовать - напишите сюда, будет очень интересно узнать как это можно сделать

Comment: можно сделать сколько угодно через CSS, скину обязательно,только вечером, я плохо знаю джаваскрипт мне нужна функция
для изменения стиля na javascript, я не понимаю, что взять за отсчет.

Comment: .slider img{
width:700px;
height:500px;
position:absolute;
animation-name: ut;
animation-duration:8s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.slider img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.slider img:nth-of-type(2) {
animation-delay: 4s;
}
.slider img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.slider img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes ut{
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
 17%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

Comment: <div class="slider">
  <img  src="/img/1.jpg" >
  <img  src="/img/2.jpg" >
  <img  src="/img/3.jpg" >
  <img  src="/img/4.jpg" >
    </div>

Comment: Ну так это же плавная смена картинок, а не фона у div-а.
Точно так же можно сделать через анимацию jquery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vpYmu/ crossfade работает только в chrome

Comment: Ого! Не знал что transition для фона работает

Comment: для firefox [только обсуждается](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052)